# How calculate Transformation matrix for quadrilateral into a rectangle?

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, homography, transformation-matrix, quadrilaterals

in the project I am taking a video of a rectangular page, four points are marked on that page, whose coordinates are known both in terms of pixels in the video (that is, their coordinates in the image) and their actual coordinates. I came across the concept of perspective transfer matrix on the internet, but I don't know how to calculate it. In fact, I want to define a transfer matrix by having these 8 points (4 points in the image and 4 real points) by which every point in the image can be converted to coordinates on the real page. Is this possible or is there a reason for it???

Like the example below in the link, but I don't know how to calculate the matrix

[Transform quadrilateral into a rectangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190483/transform-quadrilateral-into-a-rectangle)

Comment: you know it's called "homography". you'll find the system of linear equations presented in many ways by many authors. just look for it.